# Why does it here giving me 3 not 0?

Tags: c++, list

create a list:

```
list<int> l;
auto it = l.begin();
l.emplace(it, 0);
/*it =*/ l.emplace(it, 1);
/*it =*/ l.emplace(it, 2);
```

here to print

```
for (auto it : l)
    cout << it << endl; // 0 1 2
cout << "\n\n";
cout << *it << endl; // = 3
```

Why is `*it` 3 and not 0?

Comment: `auto it = l.begin()` makes `it` a past-the-end iterator. You cannot dereference a past-the-end iterator.

Comment: The `it` in your `for` loop has no connection to the `it` above. It's a different type, and refers to a different thing. (Despite the name, the `it` in your `for` loop is an `int`, not an iterator.)

Comment: `l.begin()` is an iterator to a specific element, the element that was the first in the list *at the time it was called*. At that time, the list was empty. Calling `begin` on an empty range is the same as calling `end`, it's a one-past-the-end iterator. This is so things like `std::distance` and `for` loops work exactly the same way for empty and non-empty ranges.

Comment: If you are using the compiler gcc or clang, then I suggest that you compile with `-Wshadow`. That way, the compiler will warn you in situations in which one variable shadows a different variable with an identical name, as is the case with the variable `it` in your case. You may want to read this: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471). Note that the compiler options `-Wall` and `-Wextra` do not include `-Wshadow`, you must specify this explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

At this line:

```
auto it = l.begin();
```

There is nothing in the list yet, so the beginning is also the end.

[`std::list::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace) inserts items before the given iterator, so this line:

```
l.emplace(it, 0);
```

Places `0` *before* `it`, ie it inserts at the end of the list.

`std::list` also has some of the most forgiving [iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers), and the `it` iterator is not invalidated as items are inserted into the list. `it` continues to refer to the end of the list as new items are added to the list.

Ultimately, this line:

```
cout << *it << endl;
```

Dereferences the "end" iterator, and this is not allowed. The results are *undefined*, and in this case it appears to contain the value 3. Maybe if you add another item then it'll appear to contain 4, and maybe you're seeing a hidden implementation-specific detail of the `list`. Or maybe the computer will crash or get a bad case of the [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++).